# Java return int from Object[][] via HashMap

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a question belonging Indexing. I have created a HashMap in a separate class, to get a database for a key and the coordinates of the key.

```
public class Reference_Map {

private static HashMap<String, Object[][]> map;

public HashMap<String, Object[][]> getMap() {
    return map;
}

public void setMap() {
    map = new HashMap<String, Object[][]>();
    map.put("A1", new Object [0][0]);   map.put("A2", new Object [0][1]);   
    map.put("A3", new Object [0][2]);
    map.put("B1", new Object [1][0]);   map.put("B2", new Object [1][1]);   map.put("B3", new Object [1][2]);
    map.put("C1", new Object [2][0]);   map.put("C2", new Object [2][1]);   map.put("C3", new Object [2][2]);
```

Its just a short snippet of the map, there are a lot more entries, reaching from A to P and 1 to 24 (A1 to P24). I decided to do it this way because i wanted to get the coordinates of a key to access a JTable. My Intention was to use the "setValueAt" function of the table, but it seems to need (Object o, int row, int col) to be correct.
So my questions is, how do i get the coordinates of the key in a way, i can use it for setting values to a table? Or if it really cant be done like this, how could i store my Database in a way i can use the above function?

Some sample of what I tried:

```
Reference_Map rm = new Reference_Map();
for (String s: rm.getMap().keySet()) {
  if (s.equals(ID)) {
    this.table1.setValueAt(result_short, rm.getMap().get(ID));
  }
}
```

ID is a String that contains an unknown key of the Map. result_short is a String that should be written into the Jtable (private JTable table1). The table itself is constructed like this:

```
    String[] columnNames = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24"};
    this.data = new Object[16][24];
    this.table1 = new JTable(this.data, columnNames);
```

I hope you can help me, thanks for trying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion the problem arises in the way that you chose to store the coordinates in the Map.

If you want to store the position (3,4) - storing `new Object[3][4]` it won't help you.
When you call `rm.getMap().get(ID)` you don't receive a position.

To change this you need another class, lets call it Position. You change the way you introduce coordinates to the map:

```
class Position{
 int x;
 int y;
 Position(int x, int y) {
    this.x=x;
    this.y=y;
 }
}
map.put("C2", new Position(2,1));
```

In this way, rm.getMap().get(ID) will give you a Position object (Position p). And you will be able to use it forward:

```
Position p = rm.getMap().get(ID);
this.table1.setValueAt(result_short, p.getX(), p.getY());
```

In this way you will respect:  (Object o, int row, int col).

I hope i understood the problem.

**EDIT**

To create a new instance `new Position(2,1)` you need to provide a constructor. I edited the class definition upper.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, you understood my Problem quite good. Your way seems very interesting to me. But i have a little questions left: Constructing my Map should look like this? -> "private static HashMap<String, Position> map;" and "map.put("A1", new Position(0,0));" is causing an error to me: "the constructor position is undefined". I added getters and setters to x and y in class Position

Comment: I edited the previous post to tell how to get rid of the error.